# Array length equals 1 but the array contains more elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am fairly new to javascrit and d3. I have a problem when trying to read data from a csv file using d3.csv method.

```
d3.csv("csv").then(function(x) {
                x.forEach(function(d){
                  d.Deviations= +d.Deviations;
                  d.EmotionCount= +d.EmotionCount;
                  d.NumberWord= +d.NumberWord;
                  d.SucRate= +d.SucRate;
                  d.Time2ans= +d.Time2ans;
                  data.push(d)
                }); 
            });
```

where data is an array with initially 1 element.
Then I use this data to create a radar chart.
The thing is that data.length returns 1 instead of the appropriate number of elements (118) and I can't display the other rows since I loop through data to create the visualization.
What should I do to get the length == 118.
Thank you

Comment: What have you done to debug? what's `x` before you call `forEach()` on it?

Comment: Use the data/draw the chart within the then function - the rest of your code doesn't wait for all your data to be pushed to the data array.